# Java jasper reports: sql results

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bar-chart

I have design a report that uses a data-set the results to 5 rows.When I design my bar chart, it gives me 5 separate bar charts with the same results. Is there a way to just have one bar chart or is there a setting i can use to stop paging.

```
SELECT * FROM reporting_eventcount WHERE severity>2 AND vendor='Test' AND product='Demo' AND `month` = 5 AND customer_id=4 GROUP BY event_name ORDER BY event_name ASC LIMIT 0,5;
```

This gives me 5 rows as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the chart in the summary-section to prevent printing it twice or more often. I had the same issue but then it works and the bar-chart was only printed once.

Sry for my bad english. Good luck